# Problem with unordered list and slideToggle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am making a post-comment page and I am facing a problem in making the comments unordered list slideToggle

my code-

```
$("#ccoomm").click(function() {

var pid = $(this).attr("class");
var text = $(".comment" + pid).val();
var email = $("#hidden").val();
var data = "pid=" + pid + "&text=" + text + "&email=" + email;
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(500).html('<img src="wamp.gif" /> Loading...');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comments.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("#"+pid).append(html);
        $("#flash").fadeOut(100);
        $("#text").val("");
        $(".comments"+pid).slideToggle(100);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What's exactlt the problem you are having?Can you post also your html code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
$('.'+pid).append(html);
```

instead of

```
$("#"+pid).append(html);
```